# orbBasic async interaction/interruption from client

Tags: sphero-api

I'm trying to figure out if an orbBasic program can take inputs/flags from a BT client in an asynchronous manner. 
The documented 'input' statement is blocking (but can have a timeout) and I believe the client can only send input when the orbBasic execution is waiting on the 'input' statement.

Is there a set of variables settable by the BT client that can be accessed by orbBasic? This would be more powerful and efficient. I know there may be issues with thread safety but good execution design should be able to handle this

Example usage -
app sends down target x,y location or target colour and the orbBasic handles the transition (I know macros have a fade to colour command that could do this)

Comment: OK ... I have since found that roll and set colour commands can be intercepted by the executing orbBasic program. So that answers my question (... haven't tested yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ... I have since found that roll and set colour commands can be intercepted by the executing orbBasic program. So that answers my question (... haven't tested yet).